# How to get cell custom rgb color in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with different cell colors (a few rows) and I have to set all rows with a custom color (from the first row). How can I get the first row's custom color and set all rows with the same color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the color of the first row:

   - select first row
   - open home - font - fill color - more colors
   - go to custom tab and note the parameters there (Color model, red, green blue)
2. set the color

   - select the rows you want to format
   - go to home - font - fill  color - more colors - custom tab
   - set the parameters

Comment: i didn't notice than :))